# Irrelevant graph lines in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**I have a made of chart of temperature and time using highcharts, but when i click the range of 1 week,3 day or 1 day. the chart get messy on some points and draw irrelevant graph lines in the chart like this in the picture below.**

*You can also check it on jsfiddl*e **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kakarot_123/yxeLaw59/2/)**.

*You can find the data of the chart on this link* **[Data](https://api.myjson.com/bins/m5imk)**.

[image]

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<style>
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';

#container {
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.highcharts-xaxis-grid .highcharts-grid-line {
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke: #d8d8d8;
}
.highcharts-xaxis .highcharts-tick {
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke: #d8d8d8;
}
.highcharts-minor-grid-line {
    stroke-dasharray: 2, 2;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>



</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Notice that the dataset has missing data
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/m5imk', function (data) {

  Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    chart: {
      type: 'spline'
    },
    rangeSelector: { enabled: false },
                scrollbar: { enabled: false },
     xAxis: {
         gridLineColor: '#f44242',
        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineColor: '#f44242'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      buttons: [
      {
        type: 'day',
        count: 1,
        text: '1d'
      },
      {
        type: 'day',
        count: 3,
        text: '3d'
      }, {
        type: 'week',
        count: 1,
        text: '1w'
      }, {
        type: 'month',
        count: 1,
        text: '1m'
      }, {
        type: 'month',
        count: 6,
        text: '6m'
      }, {
        type: 'year',
        count: 1,
        text: '1y'
      }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
      }],
      selected: 3
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Temperature variation by day'
    },

    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '°C',
      valueDecimals: 1,
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Temperatures',
      data: data,
      color: '#BF0B23',

        marker: 
        {
            fillColor: 'blue',
            lineWidth: 0

        }
    }]

  });
});



</script>
```

Comment: those data points are not 'Irrelevant". since, you have given unsorted data to data array, it gets randomly displayed. Sort them according to the dates and then assign them

Comment: Hi @shikhar i did sort the data according to dates same as in the file that was given in example when i check it on highchart site

Comment: is it your fiddle updated..cause i can't see any bad data represented..!

Comment: if you are talking to the data in the link >https://api.myjson.com/bins/m5imk< it got messy like this when i tried to upload it in the internet, locally i am using sorted data which is quite easy to understand, but if you have any suggestion how i can sort it out on internet then i am all ears :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `Highcharts Error #15` in a console, which means that you have unsorted data: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15/.

You need to sort your data before creating the chart:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[0] - b[0]
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wtc0pfu8/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek thanks for answer, i tried the what you have mentioned it and it does remove the error but there are still some graph lines that are getting draw on there on instead of joining 2 points directly

Comment: 'y' value is temperature and 'x' value is temperature in timestamp

Comment: Sure, but I mean what do you want to do with the 'y' value if two or more points have the same `x`? Do you want to calculate the average of the values?

Comment: No i am not calculating the temperature just displaying them, the data i am using is kind of dummy data and actual data will have some min between them.

Comment: @kakarot, So, could you explain more precisely which lines on the chart are incorrect?

Comment: there are some extra lines that getting from some points like (Thursday april 11 , 11:30 ) you will see extra line there, after reading you previous comment i think may be it is due to some points are occurring on same time so i will try to make another data with some min distance and will try it

Comment: @kakarot, Yes, these lines result from the same `x` value.

Comment: thanks for the help , btw do you have any idea about how to insert date like this ('2019-04-01 09:26:23') instead of the one i used in the data like this ('1554197280000')??

Comment: Hi @kakarot, Highcharts require timestamps, so you would have to parse it anyway. For example: `new Date("2019-04-01 09:26:23").getTime()`

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, can help me with how to integrate above  example in the code given in this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kakarot_123/p4md31k7/1/)

Comment: @kakarot, Mixing questions in one thread is not a good idea. Please create another stackoverflow question.